# Angular can't get user input passed to typescript from html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, keyup

**html**

```
<input #box (keyup.enter)="Character(box.value)"/>
```

**typescript**

```
Character(value: string) {
  console.log("print this " + value);
}
```

I confirmed the typescript code in two different places on the net and got the html code from another answer on here and even though the typescript function executes the "value" just will not print to console. I even changed my browser theme thinking that was interfering at one point. (because it changes the color of textboxes and one some sites the text blends with the box)

**Update** As you can tell from the selected answer I didn't realize my issue was that I had two textboxes which was causing the issue because the value wasn't just getting past to both as I assumed.

Comment: Honesty why the downvote?

Comment: It's working, you can check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2hkxz1

Comment: @trichetriche I figured that might have been why I was downvoted but I don't know what else so show. The project made from ng new and most of the code is still that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This working as expected :

Refer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jcrcdu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html

```
<input #box (keyup.enter)="Character(box.value)"/>

<p>{{box1name}}</p>




<input #box2 (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box2.value)"/>

<p>{{box2name}}</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  box1name = 'Angular';
  box2name = 'Angular2';

  Character(value: string) {
  this.box1name="print this for box1 :" + value;
  console.log(this.box1name);
}

  onEnter(value: string) {
  this.box2name="print this for box2: " + value;
  console.log(this.onEnter);
}


}
```

Comment: That's so weird because in my firefox console it doesn't show. See my screenshot. https://ibb.co/jyhznf

Comment: this is working in firefox also press enter key after type

Comment: I did that's how th other text which is a direct string gets triggered to print. (the text that does show in the screenshot) I'll try the dev firefox.

Comment: which version of firefox you using

Comment: the demo you posted works for me too but my own thing doesn't. ff version is ff quantum 63.0 dev version didn't make a difference.

Comment: can you add your code for .html and .ts file in question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182845/discussion-between-dinesh-ghule-and-codehelp4).

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is wrap you input in form tag, like:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
</form>
```

In typescript:

```
name = '';
submit() {
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

Comment: The typescript function runs as expected but the text of the var doesn't show. https://ibb.co/jyhznf

Comment: @codehelp4 it will call submit method when you press enter